# Интернационализация и локализация в Spring / Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Доброго времени суток!

Задался вопросом о грамотной интернационализации при разработке сайта в Spring Boot.

Перечитал массу разных решений с разных сервисов и так и не нашел удовлетворительного ответа.

Хотелось бы узнать "best practices" и услышать ваши идеи по поводу реализации. Интересует интернационализация с хранением сообщений в базе данных вместо их хранения в файле messages.properties

О том, как это реализовано у меня сейчас:
На основе данной статьи - https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7

Очевидные плюсы:

- данные хранятся в БД в одной таблице в паре locale, key, content. По
  ключу и локализации находим перевод и отдаем на фронт.

Минусы:

- для каждой группы локализации сообщения нужен свой уник. ключ
  (использую `UUID.randomUUID()` ). Т.е. Locale - ru Locale - en  У них
  один уник. ключ. Например, homePageTitle
- Другая проблема заключается в том, что для сущностей нет смысла
  хранить нужные примитивы (например, String) в самих сущностях, а
  хранить нужно их в таблице переводов. Например, для сущности Page строка title становится не нужной, так как переводы данной строки содержится в другой таблице.

Отсюда возникает вопрос - как грамотно связать таблицу (сущность) переводов с другими сущностями, чтобы можно было бы достать нужный перевод обратившись в самой сущности, а не к сущности переводов?

Нашел некоторые решения:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704729/how-to-internationalize-a-hibernate-entity
   Тут в первом варианте предлагается вместо примитива для сущности хранить HashMap. Во втором ответе предлагается связать таблицы ManyToMany
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916912/most-elegant-solution-for-internationalization-with-jpa-hibernate
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350415/internationalization-with-hibernate
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916912/most-elegant-solution-for-internationalization-with-jpa-hibernate
   В данном варианте предлагается для каждой сущности создать свою таблицу переводов, что тоже нехорошо.
5. https://thoughts-on-java.org/localized-data-hibernate/
   Также предлагается создание отдельной таблицы для каждой из сущностей
6. https://github.com/deathman92/localized
   Также нашел такую библиотеку (правда, она не работает) при помощи, которой можно использовать аннотации Localized.

Неужели нет "готового" решения или каких-либо вариантов грамотного решения данного вопроса?

Заранее благодарен за ваши советы и ответы!

Comment: Ответ ниже вам подошел?

Comment: Большое вас спасибо! Я сегодня проверю и если все ок, то отмечу ваш ответ решением. Пока не могу что-либо объективно сказать, но выглядит, как потенциальное решение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Данный вариант решения был найден мною на просторах интернета несколько лет тому назад.*

Один из возможных вариантов поддержки нескольких языков я реализовал в данном небольшом проекте: [сслыка на Гитхаб](https://github.com/Antonio112009/AndreySpring). *Данный код давно не открывал.*

Преимущества данного подхода:

1. Легкое добавление новых языков
2. Единая таблица с переводами
3. Для создания переводов для других объектов достаточно создать сущность и связующую таблицу с переводами.

Вот схема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идея проста:
В таблицу `language` пишем языки, которые мы хотели бы иметь на сайте.
В таблице `translation` пишем текст и указываем к какому языку это относится (с помощью id из таблицы `language`. `@ManyToOne`-relation.)

А дальше к таблице `translation` можем подключать разные таблицы. Пример на скриншоте иллюстрирует примитивный вариант перевода страницы. Пишется id, название текста, который надо перевести на странице и название странице. С помощью вспомогательной таблицы `text_translation`, я собираю все переводы данного текста (`@OneToMany`-relation).

Comment: Прежде всего, огромное спасибо за ваш ответ! Я посмотрел ваш код и в принципе это рабочий вариант, также как и многие другие решения. Но есть один нюанс - если не считать таблицы language & translation, то для сущности Country у вас по факту имется 3 таблицы - Country, Country_name, Country_name_translations. Возможно, что ошибаюсь (повторюсь я не эксперт в этом деле), но мне кажется, что плодить кучу таблиц не лучшая идея, но тем не менее готовое решение. Постараюсь некоторые идеи вашего проекта перенять) Еще раз спаибо)

Comment: @OrkhanHasanli Всегда пожалуйста! Если будет вариант лучше, могли бы вы добавить его реализацию сюда?

Comment: С великим удовольствим поделюсь решением, как только будет результат. Увы, пока топчусь на месте)

Comment: @OrkhanHasanli мог ли бы, пожалуйста, отметить мой ответ галкой, если он вам подошел

Answer (score 0):

Итак, я чуть покопался в Spring + Hibernate + JPA и интернационализацию реализовал следующим образом:

Рабочий демо проект - https://github.com/azerphoenix/spring-i18n-demo

1) Создадим сущности:

--- Language

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "languages")
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    // ID
    private Long languageId;

    private String languageName;

    private String locale;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "language")
    private List<Translation> translations = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

--- Translation

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "translations")
public class Translation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    // ID
    private Long translationId;

    /*@Lob*/
    @Column(name = "messagekey", length = 3000)
    private String key;

    /*@Lob*/
    @Column(name = "messagecontent", length = 100000)
    private String content;

    public Translation() {}

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "locale")
    private Language language;

}
```

Обратите внимание, что сущности Translation & Language связаны друг с другом через `@OneToMany & @ManyToOne`

Вид таблицы для Language

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+
| language_id | language_name | locale |
+-------------+---------------+--------+
|           1 | English       | en     |
|           2 | Русский       | ru     |
|           3 | Deutsch       | de     |
+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

В таблице languages хранятся все существующие (созданные через админку) языки сайта. Если у вас фиксированное кол-во языков, то можно например исопльзуя `@PostConstruct` инициализировать дефолтные языки (или как вариант создать нужные записи используя data.sql).
Например,

```
@Service
public class FirstRunService {

    @Autowired
    private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

    // Инициализируем языки
    @PostConstruct
    private void initLanguages() {

        Language de = new Language();
        de.setLanguageName("Deutsch");
        de.setLocale("de");
        languageRepository.save(de);

        Language ru = new Language();
        ru.setLanguageName("Русский");
        ru.setLocale("ru");
        languageRepository.save(ru);

        Language en = new Language();
        en.setLanguageName("English");
        en.setLocale("en");
        languageRepository.save(en);
    }
}
```

Вид таблицы для Translation:

```
+----------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| translation_id |  messagecontent  | messagekey | locale |
+----------------+------------------+------------+--------+
|              4 | english_text     | key1       |      1 |
|              5 | текст на русском | key1       |      2 |
|              6 | text auf Deutsch | key1       |      3 |
+----------------+------------------+------------+--------+
```

В таблице translations хранятся переводы, которые нужны для отображения значений в шаблоне, в формах и т.д.

> Переводы сущностей (например, Post, Page, Category) хранятся в самих
>   сущностях в виде отдельных записей! Соответственно, для них не создаются отдельные таблицы. Эту идею я перенял у плагина WPML (WordPress) и подобных ему, когда они вместо создания доп. таблиц просто создают доп. записи в той же таблице с отличием в языке.

Рассмотрим подробно. Создадим сущность Post, который будет хранить статьи нашего сайта.

Сущность Post:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    // ID
    private Long postId;

    // Заголовок статьи
    private String postTitle;

    // Отрывок статьи
    @Lob
    @Column( length = 1500 )
    private String postExcerpt;

    // Текст статьи
    @Lob
    @Column( length = 100000 )
    private String postContent;


    @Lob
    @Column(length = 3000, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String translationKey;

    // ЧПУ статьи
    private String postSlug;

    // Дата и время создания
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    public Post(){}


    // Обратите внимание на этот участок кода!
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    private Language language;
}
```

Также обратите внимание на строку translationKey.
При создании переводов генерируем `UUID.randomUUID().toString();` и назначаем их для всех переводов одной статьи.

Раз мы связали Post с сущностью Language посредством `@OneToMany & @ManyToOne` (см. выше код), то для сущности Language добавим:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "language")
private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();
```

Вид таблицы (posts) для сущности Post:

```
+---------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
| post_id | creation_date |     post_title      | post_content |      post_excerpt       | post_slug |   translationkey    | language_id |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
|       7 |             - | Überschrift Artikel | Artikel Text | Kurze Beschreibung      | post1     | Post_0001-1111-2222 |           1 |
|       8 |             - | Заголовок статьи    | Текст статьи | Краткое описание статьи | post1     | Post_0001-1111-2222 |           2 |
|       9 |             - | Post Title          | Post Content | Post Excerpt            | post1     | Post_0001-1111-2222 |           3 |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Обратите внимание на последнюю колонку language_id. По факту мы создали в одной таблице 3 записи с отличием в language_id.

Осталось настроить мультиязычность.
Идея мультиязычности с хранением записей в БД исчерпана отсюда:
https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7

```
@Component("messageSource")
public class DBMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    @Autowired
    private TranslationRepository translationRepository;

    private static final String DEFAULT_LOCALE_CODE = "az";

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String key, Locale locale) {

        Translation message = translationRepository.findByKeyAndLanguageLocale(key, locale.getLanguage()).orElse(new Translation());

        if (message == null || message.getContent() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new MessageFormat(message.getContent(), locale);
    }

}
```

Этот класс достает нужные переводы по ключу из таблицы translations.

Репозиторий для Translation

```
@Repository
public interface TranslationRepository extends JpaRepository<Translation, Long> {

    Optional<Translation> findByKeyAndLanguageLocale(String key, String locale);

    boolean existsByKeyAndLanguageLocale(String key, String locale);

}
```

Репозиторий для Language:

```
@Repository
public interface LanguageRepository extends JpaRepository<Language, Long> {

    Language findLanguageByLocale(String locale);

    boolean existsByLocale(String locale);


}
```

Для получения перевода статьи в методе контроллера принимаем locale и postSlug (или например, translationKey) и соответственно, по ним ищем статью в БД и отдаем клиенту через Model.
Пример кода:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

    @GetMapping("{/postSlug}")
    public String possView (
            @PathVariable("postSlug") String postSlug,
            Model model,
            Locale locale

    ) {

        model.addAttribute("post", postRepository.findPostByPostSlugAndLocale(postSlug, languageRepository.findLanguageByLocale(locale.getLanguage()));

        return"possView.html";
    }

}
```

Если вам потребуется получить все переводы из таблицы translations (например, чтобы отдать их в админку для возможности редактирования), то по принципу SQL Pivot используем SQL statement примерно такого плана:

Добавляем в TranslationRepository:

```
@Query(value =
            "SELECT \"messagekey\",\n" +
                    "       MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='1') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_de," +
                    "       MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='2') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_ru," +
                    "       MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='3') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_en," +
                    "       MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='1') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_de," +
                    "       MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='2') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_ru," +
                    "       MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='3') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_en " +
                    "FROM \"translations\" GROUP BY \"messagekey\";", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TranslationProjection> getAllTranslationsWithLocaleAndId();
```

Обратите внимание на сущность - TranslationProjection.
TranslationProjection - это проекция сущности Translation. 
Ее структура:

```
public interface TranslationProjection {

    String getMessagekey();

    String getContent_De();

    String getContent_Ru();

    String getContent_En();

    Long getId_De();

    Long getId_Ru();

    Long getId_En();

}
```

Вид таблицы данного SQL запроса:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| messagekey | content_de | content_ru | content_en | id_de | id_ru | id_en |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| key1       | Deutsch    | Русский    | Английский |    11 |    12 |    13 |
| key2       | Deutsch    | Русский    | Английский |    14 |    15 |    16 |
| key3       | Deutsch    | Русский    | Английский |    17 |    18 |    19 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Ну и обязательно нужно добавить конфигурацию для языков.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  /*
   * Internationalization settings
   */

  @Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    return slr;
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
  }

}
```

Соответственно, языки переключаются через `?lang=${locale}`
Например, `http://example.com/{postSlug}?lang=ru`

Не знаю насколько хороша эта реализация... Я просто объединил разные идеи в одну кучу...